How expand appbar on tap in Flutter?
In Google Calendar, you can press the AppBar and it will expand a calendar. How do I recreate this?
I can only do it through sliverappbar but that requires sliding. If I do it through modifying bottom: and adding an expanded bool it doesn't really work either cause the appbar needs to change its surface color at the same time.

As a straightforward solution that uses a built-in component (without building a new custom widget), ScaffoldMessenger can achieve this.
By calling showMaterialBanner:

Shows a [MaterialBanner] across all registered [Scaffold]s. Scaffolds
register to receive material banners from their closest
[ScaffoldMessenger] ancestor. If there are several registered
scaffolds the material banner is shown simultaneously on all of them.

An expandable banner will be presented from the top of the screen, providing the same (or at least pretty similar) behavior.
Example:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var isBannerVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (isBannerVisible) {
                setState(() {
                  isBannerVisible = false;
                });
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentMaterialBanner();
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  isBannerVisible = true;
                });
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner(
                  MaterialBanner(
                    content: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: const Center(child: Text("Content Goes Here")),
                    ),
                    // A workaround since actions must be not empty
                    actions: const [SizedBox.shrink()],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(isBannerVisible
                    ? Icons.arrow_upward
                    : Icons.arrow_downward),
                const Text('Tap me'),
              ],
            )),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: i % 2 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.grey,
              ),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The main points of the above example are:

Call ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner and provide MaterialBanner to show the banner.
Call ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentMaterialBanner(); to hide the banner.
Make sure to wrap the Scaffold body with a SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable.

Output:

